# Merge multiple columns in Pandas but skip certain items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Fruit   | Drink | Napkin
------------------------
Banana  | Coke  | No
Apple   | No    | Red
Kumquat | Beer  | White
No      | No    | Green
```

And I want to combine the columns into a new column but, and this is the bit I'm having trouble with, I have to skip the "Nos", i.e. to produce:

```
Fruit   | Drink | Napkin | Combined
-----------------------------------
Banana  | Coke  | No     | Banana, Coke
Apple   | No    | Red    | Apple, Red
Kumquat | Beer  | White  | Kumquat, Beer, White
No      | No    | Green  | Green
```

I can find lots of advice on combining the columns but nothing on how to do that whilst skipping the nos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the No to NaNs, [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get rid of them and aggregate with [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df['combined'] = (df
 .replace('No', pd.NA)
 .stack()
 .groupby(level=0)
 .agg(','.join)
 )
```

Output:

```
     Fruit Drink Napkin            combined
0   Banana  Coke     No         Banana,Coke
1    Apple    No    Red           Apple,Red
2  Kumquat  Beer  White  Kumquat,Beer,White
3       No    No  Green               Green
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sets.

```
df['combined'] = df.agg(set,1).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x-{'No'}))

     Fruit Drink Napkin            combined
0   Banana  Coke     No         Coke,Banana
1    Apple    No    Red           Red,Apple
2  Kumquat  Beer  White  Beer,White,Kumquat
3       No    No  Green               Green
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are looking for a 'pythonic' solution here, but why don't you just remove that bit of string from your 'Combined' column ?

Suggestion:

```
#Preparing data
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Fruit']=pd.Series(['Banana','Apple','Kumquat','No'])
df['Drink']=pd.Series(['Coke','No','Beer','No'])
df['Napkin']=pd.Series(['No','Red','White','Green'])

df['Combined']=df['Fruit']+','+df['Drink']+','+df['Napkin']
df['Combined']=df['Combined'].str.replace(',No','').str.replace('No,','')
```

The only issue I see with this, is if you encounter a string in your columns that would start with 'No*' (Nostradamus or something). But in that case, you could just remove the values from the original columns ?

Answer (score 0):

imho, the simplest way is this:

```
df['Combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x!='No']), 1)

>>> df
'''
     Fruit Drink Napkin              Combined
0   Banana  Coke     No          Banana, Coke
1    Apple    No    Red            Apple, Red
2  Kumquat  Beer  White  Kumquat, Beer, White
3       No    No  Green                 Green
```